# How to construct confidence intervals for multiple choice survey responses where the measurement is the percentage of respondents?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, binomial-distribution, proportion, survey

Say I have $k$ categories of responses to a survey question from $n$ respondents. Assume n of each category is about 50, so we can't just work off asymptotic behavior necessarily.

How do I compute confidence intervals from the survey results for each response category?

My point estimate for $\mu_k$ is obviously $\hat{\pi}_k = \frac{n_k}{N}$.

I thought of just using a binomial standard error and constructing the intervals with something like the Wilson interval for smaller $n$. But I'm not sure that's quite right. We'd then be computing $k$ independent binomial intervals, and I feel like their significance levels would need to be adjusted to account for multiple comparisons. That seems to be what SAS does, [in fact](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/15/confidence-intervals-multinomial-proportions.html#:%7E:text=A%20categorical%20response%20variable%20can,each%20category%20in%20the%20population.) (Chi-square with 1 d.f. and $\frac{\alpha}{k}$ cutpoint).

A multinomial chi-square test seems to test for the joint goodness of fit of all response estimates against hypothesized values of $\pi_k$, not compute intervals.

This is an example dataset with $k = 5$

```
-----------------------------------
Brand   |  N   |   %   | Share %
-----------------------------------

Brand1  |  20  |  20%  |  9%

Brand2  |  40  |  40%  | 19%

Brand3  |  45  |  45%  | 21%

Brand4  |  35  |  35%  | 16%

Brand5  |  75  |  70%  | 35%
-----------------------------------
Total   | 215  |       | 100%
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: In an exploratory analysis, I'd write "... individual 95% Wilson confidence intervals, without correction for multiple testing". Otherwise it depends on the exact nature of the statistical design etc. Good question!